# How to handle version number changes in design files?

Tags: c#, numbers, version, .net-assembly

There is a program with many projects. The forms design file for each project contains a manually inputted version number "ver 1.0" etc... Every time there is a version change it seems to be a bit of a pain. What is the best approach to updating version numbers for design files. I could update this from AssemblyInfo using System.Reflection but is this the best practice? If it is, should I do this directly in the design file or is importing libraries in a design file bad.

Thanks.

EDIT: By design file I refer to FormName.Designer.cs. (form design file)

Comment: What do you mean by "design file"

Comment: My apologies, I was referring to a Forms Designer file (ie. FormName.Designer.cs.

Comment: The designer file is overwritten by the WinForms designer every time there is a change in the Design view. So, how do you ensure that your version number string isn't overwritten?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean Sameer. Currently the version numbers are just changes in Windows Form Designer. The method I mentioned up above (using System.Reflection) just uses "System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName()
.Version.ToString()" to pull during runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the version number from the assembly like this:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString()
```

or you could write a static class with a static string like this:

```
public static class Global
{
    public static string Version = "V. 1.1";
}
```

Comment: Currently the only method I had thought about using is the first one you listed. Is it best to do this in the Form.cs file or the Form.Desginer.cs file?

Comment: Don't mess with the Designer-file, simply leave it alone. Add it in the Form.cs file.